# Android Studio : Getting error during build gradle

Tags: android, android-studio

I am getting below error during build gradle.

```
Error:(7, 8) error: cannot access ScrollingView class file for android.support.v4.view.ScrollingView
```

When I choose jump to source option from  error  its open this class 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are using both V4 & V7. Try out changing the class path order from project structure.

[image]